# Executing multiple command in command prompt using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm just a lurker and wondering if I can create a vbscript that can run command prompt together with the other command that I want to type in command prompt.

Here's what I want to do:

I want to create a wifi hotspot using command prompt with this command;

```
`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=NAME key=PASSWORD 

netsh wlan start hostednetwork'
```

and another thing, can anyone helped me how can i share my network using command prompt to make my laptop wifi hotspot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the "Shell" object to run commands:

```
strText="netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=NAME key=PASSWORD"
Set shll = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Return = shll.Run(strText, 1, TRUE)
```

you can add as many "shll.run" commands as you need to - the TRUE flag above will make VBScript wait for the command to finish before continuing the script.

You would be better off looking at Powershell for sharing network connections.